# Codeception acceptance test to accept popup

Tags: php, testing, automated-tests, codeception

I am currently using Codeception 2.2 in order to test an application. The steps I have so far are as below:

```
<?php 
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('perform actions and see result');
$I->amOnPage('/index.php');
$I->fillField('username', 'admin');
$I->fillField('password', 'password');
$I->click('Sign in');
$I->amOnPage('/index.php?module=CustomReports&view=Edit');
$I->fillField('relatedclient', '******');
$I->fillField('policynumber', '****');
$I->click('Save');
$I->see('You are being redirected to the clients isa report.');
$I->click('OK');    // This is where it fails
$I->see('Client ISA Statement');
?>
```

Currently I am using PHP with inline JS which is where the error happens. I am wondering how I can accept the window.alert in order to go to the next page. I have tried `$I->click('OK')` but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a really confusing Thing in codeception.
You can try it with

```
$I->acceptPopup()
```

Unfortunately it could be that it doesnt work. This is caused by selenium2 drivers. Sometimes they cant get the hook when browsers are throwing  alerts. I saw really really confusing stuff regarding these alerts.

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally worked:

```
$I->waitForElementVisible("//button[contains(@class, 'x-btn-text') and text() = 'Yes']");
$I->click("//button[contains(@class, 'x-btn-text') and text() = 'Yes']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this approach:

```
    $I = $this->tester;

    $I->amGoingTo("check whether any JS alert appears and accept it");
    $I->executeInSelenium(function (\Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriver $webdriver) {
        try {
            $webdriver->wait(1.5, 200)->until(
                WebDriverExpectedCondition::alertIsPresent()
            );
            $webdriver->switchTo()->alert()->accept();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo("###ERROR: oops, didnt manage to find the alert. Exception: '" . $e->getTraceAsString() . "' 
            Please contact test developers for investgation");
        }
    });
    if (strlen($this->errorMessage) > 0) {
        $I->comment($this->errorMessage);
    }
```

Hope this helps You.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that might work is to use a more specific selector for the 'OK'
 button.

Here's one that worked for me:

```
$I->click("//button[contains(@class, 'x-btn-text') and text() = 'OK']");
```

In this case 'button' is the HTML tag I want to click, 'x-btn-text' is the class of the button and 'OK' is the text inside the tag.

If the button has a unique id (or you can add one), it's much simpler:

```
<button id="button_id" type="button">OK</button>

$I->click('#button_id');
```

Note that this may not work unless you're using WebDriver for your acceptance test.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
 try {
    $I->click('i.e. CLOSE BUTTON OF YOUR POPUP ELEMENT');
    } catch (\PHPUnit_Framework_Exception $e) {
       // failed assertion handled
    }
```